# Send arguments from VBA to VBS then again pull an argument/variable from VBS to VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbscript

I am executing VBS files from VBA using Wscript.Shell and passing some arguments to VBS. Now, I want the Wscript.Shell wait for the return of the arguments/variable from VBS. Any lead, how do I achieve this? Thanks

**VBA code is:**

```
Sub LaunchScript()

    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1 
    Dim scriptPath As String, MyMsg As String
    Dim Return_VBS_Val
    
    scriptPath = "C:\path\x.vbs"
    MyMsg = "I got into VBS"
     
     Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
     wsh.Run """" & scriptPath & """ """ & MyMsg & """", windowStyle, waitOnReturn
    
    'Return_VBS_Val = argument from x.vbs  >>>>> I want to pull the argument from VBS here and store it in this VBA Variable

End sub
```

**x.vbs code:**

```
Dim Return_VBS_Val 

'something to do here

Msgbox Wscript.Arguments(0)

Return_VBS_Val = "Hello VBA"
```

Comment: Do you know you can execute commands from inside VBA without needed to use `WScript.Shell`? Also, if you pass the arguments into the VBS you already have them available in the VBA?

Comment: You only need to escape the literal quotes that are part of the command by doubling them, so say you're trying to execute `cscript.exe "C:\path with spaces\x.vbs" "I got into VBS"` then when run with `wsh.Run()` the string would be `"cscript.exe ""C:\path with spaces\x.vbs"" ""I got to VBS"""` or with variables, it would be `"cscript.exe """ & scriptPath & """ """ & MyMsg & """"`. You also cannot execute VBS directly you should be calling through `cscript.exe`.

Comment: To pass an argument to VBScript is simple. To send an argument back to VBA, I think it cannot be done in the way you try. The last code line of the VBA procedure should be the one running the script. Otherwise, Excel wait for the rest of the code to be run. To sent back a function result or something else, VBS in discussion must create an object from the existing Excel session and run a procedure of the respective workbook, using the necessary argument as Sub parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WScript.Shell.Exec - read output from stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32492879)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture Output of WScript Shell Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631335)

Comment: There is no reason to do this. Sounds like an XY Problem. If you tell us what you are actually trying to do, instead of how you are trying to do it, then we can help you better.

Comment: @HackSlash Thanks for your response, Tim's answer has satisfied my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using StdOut:

```vb
Sub LaunchScript()

    Dim scriptPath As String, MyMsg As String
    
    scriptPath = "C:\path\x.vbs"
    MyMsg = "I got into VBS"
     
    Debug.Print "Ouput: " & ExecShellCmd("cscript.exe """ & _
                         scriptPath & """ """ & MyMsg & """")
    
End Sub

Public Function ExecShellCmd(FuncExec As String) As String
    ExecShellCmd = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") _
                    .exec("cmd.exe /c " & FuncExec).stdout.readall
End Function
```

VBS file:

```
Msgbox  Wscript.Arguments(0) 'read input
Wscript.Echo "Hello VBA"   'pass output
```

Comment: Just another take on [Capture Output of WScript Shell Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631335).

Comment: Pretty much everything here is “just another take on xxxx” if you want to look at it that way…

Comment: Exactly, so adding another is helping who? Let's face it we are talking about languages that have been around for 20+ years, if how to read standard output from a command in VBScript hasn't been answered by now it never will. You just add to the problem when you answer questions like this.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks Tim, that helped me to move on!