# Unable to redirect output from VBA with cmd in hidden mode

Tags: vba, shell, wsh

Am trying to redirect output from cmd to a text file using `Wscript.shell` script. It works when cmd window is in active mode. But doesn't work with cmd windows style is 0 (hidden mode).

```
Dim objShell : Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim cmd : cmd = "cmd /K sftp  " & sftpusername & "@" & sftpserver & " > output.txt"
Oresult = objShell.Run (cmd, 0, false)
```

The output file is empty. However, when I change the window style to 1, I can see the data on output file.

Comment: Try instead reading from stdout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69367057/478884

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the response. But I have a requirement to run cmd in hidden mode. can that be achieved though Stdout, if so could you share some instruction on that.

Comment: Sorry I missed that exec always needs to run with a visible window - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297699/hide-command-prompt-window-when-using-exec

Comment: Maybe try providing a full path for `output.txt`

Comment: I tried that too, but when cmd is not visible there is not output. the file is empty.

Comment: If the file is empty then perhaps there was a problem with the command?  Maybe try redirecting both stdout and stderr to the same file, and see if there's any content produced?   https://stackoverflow.com/a/1420981/478884

Comment: Hi sorry for the long silence. Well there was not problem with the command as it was working fine when the cmd window is visible. but the issue is when window is invisible.

Comment: But managed to finish my task, using powershell.